# How to use (import) com.aldebaran.qi.helper.proxies.*; on android studio, so that it works on my phone?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pepper

I want to create an application under android studio, to control the pepper robot from my phone. I have installed the `QiSdk` and I use some of its features to connect my phone to pepper by ip address. However, I would now like to use the `ALTextToSpeech` import to make the robot talk. But the `helper` and `helper.proxies` imports are not integrated in the `QiSdk`, I have already tried to import a library `.jar`, java for pepper. I can compile the application under android studio but when I launch the application from my phone, it stops when it needs to use the functions in the `.jar`.

Comment: Thank you, I've been blocking for several days now, but I'll still do some research. If I can't find it, I'll edit my post so that it's easier and clearer, as you advised me to do !

Comment: Are you using a Pepper under 2.9+ Naoqi version?

Comment: Yes I use the 2.5.5 naoqi version, for Pepper.

Comment: Hello Lucas, There is no official support for Android apps under naoqi 2.5. The Java library is on the github : https://github.com/aldebaran/libqi-java/tree/release-2.5 but not sure how much this will help.

Answer (score 0):

The QiSDK is only for a Pepper with NAOqi 2.9 (or above), for NAOqi 2.5 you should instead be using [the NAOqi Java SDK](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/dev/java/index_java.html).

Comment: than there are no options to connect directly to the services from QiSDK on 2.9?